# Jump and Call on same line in assembly

Tags: function, assembly, x86, call, intel

I want to know if there is a way to make a conditional decision and call a function based on that result.

For example. I want to compare something. I want to do the function call if they are even. However, the way I wrote my function I need to call the function and not jump to it. (based on the way my function handles the stack) Is there a way to do that? I have copied my code in as shown, it does not compile.

```
.endOfForLoop: cmp  dword [ebp - 4], 1 ; compares the boolean to one
je call print_prime ; if it is one then prime needs to be printed
jmp call print_not_prime ; otherwise it is not prime
```

Using NASM, x86 32 bit assembly, linux, intel

Comment: jumps and calls are mutually exclusive and both do not appear together as you've shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just jump around the function call as if you'd implement an if-then-else:

```
.endOfForLoop:
    cmp dword [ebp-4],1
    jne .not_prime
    call print_prime
    jmp .endif
.not_prime:
    call print_not_prime
.endif:
```

You could also use function pointers and the `cmov` instruction to make your code branchless, but I advise against writing code like this as it is harder to understand and not actually faster as all branch predictors I know do not try to predict indirect jumps at all.

```
.endOfForLoop:
    cmp dword [ebp-4],1
    mov eax,print_prime
    mov ebx,print_not_prime
    cmovne eax,ebx
    call eax
```

Comment: @frillybob, If you're doing nothing else after the call, then you can just jmp to the call destination instead, the return from that call will return to the caller from the jumping routine, saving you a call-return pair.